# Nonclustered index column order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, nonclustered-index

I have a nonclustered index (called `NCIDX1`) on `col1, col2` of a table. I included `col3, col4, col5, col6` as included columns in this order.

If I run the following query:

```
select 
     col1,col2 
from 
     tbl1
where 
     col3 = something
and
     col4 = something
and
     col5 = something
```

Is it any different than running:

```
select 
     col3,col2 ,col4
from 
     tbl1
where 
     col1 = something
and
     col5 = something
```

?

What I am trying to say is, when we create a covering index like the above, and we change the order in which we are accessing data, will it still take advantage of this covering index?

Also, the order of equality columns (amongst themselves) and non equality columns (amongst themselves)... does it matter? Like `where equalitycol2='' and equalitycol1=''`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, an index should be on

```
(equalitycol1, equalitycol2, ..., nonequalitycol1, , nonequalitycol2, ...)
INCLUDE
(outputonlycol1, outputonlycol2, ...)
```

Simply (ignoring ranges) this breaks down into

- equalitycol: `WHERE equalitycol = something`. Most selective first. SARGable. Seeks.
- nonequalitycol: `WHERE nonequalitycol <> something`. Residual filters
- outputonlycol: `SELECT outputonlycol`. No filtering or ordering

`ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` columns will be equality or non-equality columns.

In this case...

Query 1 doesn't match the index at all, really, so most likely won't use the index. However, the optimiser *may* decide it's cheaper to use the index then use other table access such as a table scan or a RID/bookmark lookup.

For query 2, the optimiser may decide to use the index because `col1` would be an equality match. And then use the unsorted `col5` from the `INCLUDE`. YMMV, but there is a higher chance.

For the `WHERE` clause order, no: the optimiser works it out. Two indexes `(col1, col2)` and `(col2, col1)` are different though. Note `(col1, col2)` will be contained by `(col1, col2, col3, col4)` though so the first isn't needed.